# scala.collection.mutable.Map.+= do not work?

Tags: android, scala

I am using Scala in Android, here is one of the test code:

```
  def bookList() = {
    val res = resource.getAssets.open("demo.png")
    val image = Drawable.createFromStream(res, "demo.png")
    val map = Map[String, Drawable]()
    for (i <- 1 to 100) {
      map += ("test book" -> image)
    }
    map
  }
```

but the return result from the bookList method always get a map of size one. so I am confused, is that any possible reason for this wrong behavior?

Comment: plus, I use the right map.

Comment: The key doesnt change in your case, so you ll always have one item in the map

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this

```
def bookList() = {
  val res = resource.getAssets.open("demo.png")
  val image = Drawable.createFromStream(res, "demo.png")
  val map = Map[String, Drawable]()
  for (i <- 1 to 100) {
    map += (s"test book$i" -> image)
  }
  map
}
```